# Ive amended as requested and the gas question is still on hold. Why?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question

*Captain America*    **I can do this all day.**    */Captain America*

This is a different question. The question **here** is, Once I have addressed all the reasons given by the moderators and the help center, and am still on hold, what could possibly be the remaining problem?

The other question that confused Vincent, was: Since my original (unamended) question

> asks about the
>
> Effects of world elements, including technology on specific aspects of
>   that world's environment

why is it off topic. That question was answered. I made the corrections. and the question is still on hold.

Hope this helps explain the new meta question.

I've probably spent three hours since last night, accommodating the requests for amendment, as communicated by the elected moderators at this point.

[What gases are made by a live, crackling, exposed electrical wire?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/92830/what-gases-are-made-by-a-live-crackling-exposed-electrical-wire)

I've consolidated to a single question, as requested. Visited and read the help center, 5 times since last night, as requested. and addressed the problems identified in my other question here on meta in edits, as requested.

[No clue why the gas question is not world building](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5386/no-clue-why-the-gas-question-is-not-world-building)

I am also adding links here, as requested.

I have also shown evidence of other questions that have the same identified flaws and are not on hold.

Please remove the hold on my question or provide feedback so that I may try to salvage it.

I realize I'm stupid, but hope this suffices.

Comment: There is no need to post the same question twice.

Comment: Please refrain from becoming hostile towards other community members. While it may not have been your intent, your recent edit could come across in that fashion. We all want good questions and good communication to have a healthy community.

Comment: The question is closed and you want it reopened. Different wording, same thing.

Comment: @Vincent "Why was this question put on hold?" and "I've edited this question, why hasn't it been reopened?" are similar but ultimately different questions.

Comment: @frostfyre Vincent came across as 'hostile' and so I assumed she preferred that level of banter.

Comment: @Vincent I have been clear that what I want is clear guidelines and uniform application. I would also like the help center to more clearly state what is on topic, as my post CLEARLY falls within the guidelines as they are stated in the help center. I truly don't care if the question is opened or closed. I'll post the question again within your phrasing preferences and hope to bypass this whatever-it-is.

Comment: The word is blunt.

Comment: @vincent Be aware that blunt comes across as hostile. Of course, it bothered Frostfyre, not you. So no biggie here AFAIK.

Comment: The question, well, in question, has been reopened.

Comment: Thank you. My characters thank you as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is still on hold because it has received 3 of the 5 votes necessary for it to be reopened. Any user who has earned at least 3000 reputation can vote to open and close questions.

Personally I don't think the question is about worldbuilding. 
If we take a look at the core of your question you say.

> **My sole question is whether the gaseous makeup of air is changed by electricity running along a wire**.

This isn't a question about worldbuilding. This is about electrochemistry.

You mention that there are other questions that are similar but not on hold. Our site isn't perfect people make mistakes and questions slip through the cracks. After you pointed out that question it has already acquired one close vote.

To quote [Secespitus](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5387/26175)

> **We should close questions like that even if they are popular. They are not a good fit for the site and they make people from other sites think that questions like that are the norm on this site.**

Comment: *"This isn't a question about worldbuilding. This is about physics."*, actually it's chemistry

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. The value of this site is that there are knowledgeable people who  help other knowledgeable people craft more legitimate worlds. Worlds are driven by physics and chemistry, so neither of those are reasons to say something isn't world building. Ex: Most of the space-based questions are purely astrophysics questions. You create a false dichotomy by saying the site is geared towards creating worlds, and then exclude questions drawing from the world for which we have the best understanding. (Earth, in case that isn't clear.)

Comment: @DPT There's a difference between asking, "How can I leverage known science to get desired effect X?" (a worldbuilding question) and, "Can this known science get desired effect X?" (a science question). The astrophysics questions (mostly) fall under the former category; from what I understand, that community also doesn't particularly like speculative questions.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T After consulting with my chemistry expert I concede that you are correct on that point. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: We've had the "real world" question before and the decision was that so long as the question is relevant to building a world then the question is allowed. https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3872/is-a-real-world-question-off-topic